# Oracle: Date Range

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the below Query & table:

Problem:
I'm trying to capture IDs that were Reassigned for that month.

For example the month of August total number of ReAssigned would be 1 and not 3

How can this be captured?

*I need to count Per Month, for example. How mamy ids were reassigned for the month of August, Sept, ect.*

So, the Most_Rent_Assigment date needs to fall within the month
Aug: 8/1-8/31
Sept: 9/1-9/30
Then count to capture how many ids were reassigned in that month

```
 ,CASE WHEN 
H.FIRST_ASSGN_DT IS NULL THEN 'UnAssigned'
WHEN h.TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_REASSIGNMENTS = 0 OR h.TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_REASSIGNMENTS IS NULL 
AND h.FIRST_ASSGN_DT IS NOT   NULL   THEN 'NewlyAssigned'  
ELSE 'ReAssigned'
END ASSIGNED_STATUS
```

Table:

```
ID    Total_Number_Reassignment  Most_Recent_Assignment    StartDate    *Assigned Status   
1          2                           11/01/2016           08/1/2017      ReAssigned
2          3                           08/02/2017           08/01/2017     ReAssigned
3          0                                                08/15/2017     NewlyAssigned   
4          5                           12/01/2016           09/01/2017     ReAssigned
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date ranges in Oracle can be accomplished by using `BETWEEN`.

If the columns are type `DATE` then you can just do: `WHERE TRUNC(Most_Recent_Assignment) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2017-08-01') AND TO_DATE('2017-08-31')`

Note: the `TRUNC` will truncate the date to midnight, so you don't lose results based on time of day.

Edit:
OP clarified his question.

To count occurrences for a particular month, you can group by month.

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR('Most_Recent_Assignment', 'mm'),
    COUNT(TO_CHAR('Most_Recent_Assignment', 'mm'))
FROM TABLE
WHERE ...
GROUP BY TO_CHAR('Most_Recent_Assignment', 'mm')
```

`TO_CHAR` parses a date as a string. `mm` will return a 2-digit month. You can replace it with `Month` to get the name of the month.

The group will put all months together.

Comment: I need to be able to catpure all results, not just August. So creating a Where clause to limit my results will not work.